# PosgtreSQL GIN + BTree ordering

Tags: postgresql, index, performance, execution-plan, query-performance

I have a table with simple structure (id, metadata_json, stamp), stamp is a timestamp and has Btree index on it. MetadataJson is a jsonb with GIN index.

The table has 25M rows. I am using PostgreSQL 10.

```
                 Table "public.metadata"
    Column     |            Type             | Modifiers
---------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 id            | uuid                        | not null
 metadata_json | jsonb                       |
 stamp         | timestamp without time zone |
Indexes:
    "metadata_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "metadata_idx" gin (metadata_json)
    "stamp_idx" btree (stamp)
```

The query I am executing is quite simple:

```
select * from metadata where metadata_json @> '{"someBool": true}'
         AND stamp >= '01-01-2016' ORDER BY stamp DESC LIMIT 100;
```

My idea how it should work: I have a btree on stamp, hence it should go by the index in reverse order, then it should test rows on the json restriction (it has selectivity 40%). I would expect it to return in few milliseconds.

```
QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=80598.46..80598.71 rows=100 width=381) (actual time=445064.728..445064.791 rows=100 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=80598.46..80607.46 rows=3600 width=381) (actual time=445064.724..445064.754 rows=100 loops=1)
         Sort Key: stamp DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 109kB
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on metadata  (cost=66591.00..80460.87 rows=3600 width=381) (actual time=2881.164..444283.520 rows=1437024 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((metadata_json @> '{"someBool": true}'::jsonb) AND (stamp >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
               Heap Blocks: exact=882439
               ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=66591.00..66591.00 rows=3600 width=0) (actual time=2599.415..2599.415 rows=0 loops=1)
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on metadata_idx  (cost=0.00..260.25 rows=25100 width=0) (actual time=1762.166..1762.166 rows=10041746 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (metadata_json @> '{"someBool": true}'::jsonb)
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on stamp_idx  (cost=0.00..66328.69 rows=3600034 width=0) (actual time=760.136..760.136 rows=3591329 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (stamp >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
 Planning time: 5.008 ms
 Execution time: 445072.043 ms
(14 rows)
```

From the plan it seems that the planner has statistics really off, but the table is analyzed, sampling was set to 1000.

---

Edit: after some searching I found out that postgres does not have statistics for jsonb data type... Can you please hint me how this type of query can be optimized?

Edit 2: if I disable bitmap scan, the query is extremely fast (2 millis). But I do not think its a good solution...

Edit 3: fencing (WITH CTE Statement)

```
Limit  (cost=1489968.48..1489968.73 rows=100 width=56) (actual time=447543.199..447543.262 rows=100 loops=1)
  CTE t
    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on metadata  (cost=67228.70..1408830.13 rows=3600034 width=381) (actual time=1045.566..441897.315 rows=3591329 loops=1)
          Recheck Cond: (stamp >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
          Heap Blocks: exact=1229457
          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on stamp_idx  (cost=0.00..66328.69 rows=3600034 width=0) (actual time=663.960..663.960 rows=3591329 loops=1)
                Index Cond: (stamp >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
  ->  Sort  (cost=81138.35..81147.35 rows=3600 width=56) (actual time=447543.197..447543.227 rows=100 loops=1)
        Sort Key: t.stamp DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 109kB
        ->  CTE Scan on t  (cost=0.00..81000.76 rows=3600 width=56) (actual time=1045.577..446935.261 rows=1437024 loops=1)
              Filter: (metadata_json @> '{"someBool": true}'::jsonb)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 2154305
Planning time: 0.169 ms
Execution time: 447692.843 ms
```

Edit 4: Fencing (Subselect in FROM)

```
Limit  (cost=1798933.42..1811851.02 rows=100 width=381) (actual time=198282.400..198282.400 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Subquery Scan on foo  (cost=1798933.42..2186461.48 rows=3000 width=381) (actual time=198282.397..198282.397 rows=0 loops=1)
        Filter: (foo.metadata_json @> '{"someBool": true}'::jsonb)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 3591329
        ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1798933.42..2148961.13 rows=3000028 width=381) (actual time=184803.964..195869.763 rows=3591329 loops=1)
              Workers Planned: 2
              Workers Launched: 2
              ->  Sort  (cost=1797933.40..1801683.43 rows=1500014 width=381) (actual time=184599.426..188532.836 rows=1197110 loops=3)
                    Sort Key: metadata.stamp DESC
                    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 461368kB
                    ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on metadata  (cost=67228.70..1382579.88 rows=1500014 width=381) (actual time=1171.006..178501.269 rows=1197110 loops=3)
                          Recheck Cond: (stamp >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
                          Heap Blocks: exact=408005
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on stamp_idx  (cost=0.00..66328.69 rows=3600034 width=0) (actual time=728.401..728.401 rows=3591329 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (stamp >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
Planning time: 6.704 ms
Execution time: 198509.456 ms
```

Forcibly disabled bitmap scan

```
set enable_bitmapscan = off;
explain analyze select * from metadata where metadata_json @> '{"someBool": true}' AND stamp >= '01-01-2015' ORDER BY stamp DESC LIMIT 100;

Limit  (cost=0.44..256064.27 rows=100 width=381) (actual time=0.065..1.814 rows=100 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan Backward using stamp_idx on metadata  (cost=0.44..18423793.42 rows=7195 width=381) (actual time=0.064..1.777 rows=100 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (stamp >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
        Filter: (metadata_json @> '{"someBool": true}'::jsonb)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 126
Planning time: 0.180 ms
Execution time: 1.856 ms
```

Edit 5
Only compound gin(stamp, metadata_json) index present:

```
explain analyze select * from metadata where metadata_json @> '{"someBool": true}
         AND stamp >= '01-01-2016' ORDER BY stamp DESC LIMIT 100;
Limit  (cost=14132.36..14132.61 rows=100 width=381) (actual time=308836.991..308837.052 rows=100 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=14132.36..14141.36 rows=3600 width=381) (actual time=308836.988..308837.018 rows=100 loops=1)
        Sort Key: stamp DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 109kB
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on metadata  (cost=124.90..13994.77 rows=3600 width=381) (actual time=3160.418..308183.328 rows=1437024 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: ((stamp >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (metadata_json @> '{"someBool": true}'::jsonb))
              Heap Blocks: exact=882439
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on metadata_stamp_metadata_json_idx  (cost=0.00..124.00 rows=3600 width=0) (actual time=2883.484..2883.484 rows=1437024 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((stamp >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (metadata_json @> '{"someBool": true}'::jsonb))
Planning time: 0.233 ms
Execution time: 308857.051 ms
```

---

**Final solution:**

I have decomposed the json to key-value and stored it as table "recordId, key, value, stamp". And I created a btree index on these - and the result is returned universally in few millis. I do not think there is any good universal solution for json without statistics.

Correct answer goes to Evan, as this is probably the best what can be done in jsonb structure.

Comment: What if you create a gin index with both columns?

Comment: ERROR:  data type timestamp without time zone has no default operator class for access method "gin"

Comment: Ah yes, there are restrictions on the types that a gin index can use.

Comment: I have added an edit - the problem seems to be in bitmap scan...but disabling it using SET seems quite hacky to me.

Comment: You need the extension: (Run `create extension btree_gin;` once in the database to be able to create that index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem that you're suffering from here is that the stats on jsonb suck. That's a known issue. It won't ever get fixed either.

```
->  Bitmap Index Scan on metadata_idx  (cost=0.00..260.25 rows=25100 width=0) (actual time=1762.166..1762.166 rows=10041746 loops=1)
    Index Cond: (metadata_json @> '{"someBool": true}'::jsonb)
```

Here PostgreSQL expects 25100 but the low selectivity is giving back 10041746. The timestamp estimates are pretty accurate returning 3.6 M. PostgreSQL expects to have to dig through that 3.6 M To find a meager 25,100. That's a lot of digging. So instead it does an index scan on the jsonb.

You have a few options.

- Create compound GIN index as ypercube suggested.

  ```
  CREATE EXTENSION btree_gin;
  CREATE INDEX ON metadata USING gin(stamp, metadata_json);
  ```
- Add an index on metadata_json->someBool
- Use an optimization fence.

  ```
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM metadata
    WHERE stamp >= '01-01-2016'
    ORDER BY stamp DESC
    OFFSET 0
  )
  WHERE metadata_json @> '{"someBool": true}'
  ORDER BY stamp DESC
  LIMIT 100;
  ```

You may also want to look into [`jsonb_path_ops`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html). It can also be used to create a compound GIN index,

```
CREATE INDEX ON metadata USING gin(stamp, metadata_json jsonb_path_ops);
```

Comment: I have tried the fencing approach (see edit) and the performance is similar to the original query...

Comment: @malejpavouk updated, put the sort order inside the CTE and please update the plan. remove it from the outer.

Comment: @malejpavouk updated again, try that fence model.

Comment: 200 seconds...behaves quite rationally when timerange is reduced, but still requires a lot of RAM and is much slower than original with disabled bitmap scan (takes 2 millis). I tried also subselect in where, but this had worse performance.

Comment: + added explain analyze for the original query with disable bitmap scan, which works quite as expected (but is hacky)....

Comment: I will try tomorrow the compound index - I had today some problems with it as we do not have this extension available on our installation (hence it throws some errors that control file is missing). Index on the field only would be a good solution, unfortunatelly we do not control what exactly is in those jsons :-((..those are customer specific data

Comment: @malejpavouk did you try the composite gin index? I'm curious how it performs. Oh, we were cross-commenting ;)

Comment: @malejpavouk you still have a sort in there, do you have an index on `stamp::timestamp without time zone`? let's see the table `\d`

Comment: Anothe rhack idea would be to try the "fencing FROM" with `LIMIT 10000` inside there. It's a hack and not guaranteed to always return 100 results, even if there more in the table of course. But still, it would be nice to see efficiency and what plan is produced.

Comment: And please use sane date literals.

Comment: I have added description of the table. The hack with limit would work if the data in json was controlled by us, unfortunatelly those are generic customer data. And it /may/ happen that the field in json will have really low selectivity. And this would create a lot of headache to some unlucky guy trying to find the bug in few years, when the hack manifests itself...

Comment: @malejpavouk does it change the plan if you remove both of the `DESC` leaving it to `ASC`? Pg10 should be smarter than that anyway.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I will try tomorrow, its midnight here :-)...But I believe I saw today that PG was reporting both going through the index in forward and back direction (when I was fiddling with ASC/DESC).

Comment: I have added compound index and removed indexes on single columns to motivate planner to use the compound index. It helped a bit for the original query, but 300s. With FROM subselect fence it is 183s, which is approximatelly the same as two separate indexes.

Comment: @EvanCarroll the opposite ordering has almost the same results.